# Making <a> behave the same as <input type="image" />?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Inside our web application, we have some messaging functionality for messaging other members. This form is receiving a facelift, and I need to replace some functionality:

```
<input type="image" name="cancel" src="/rpc/button/?text=Cancel" />
<input type="image" name="delete" src="/rpc/button/?text=Delete Draft" />
<input type="image" name="send" src="/rpc/button/?text=Send Message" />
<input type="image" name="save" src="/rpc/button/?text=Save Draft" />
```

I need to change those buttons to use the new CSS buttons we have:

```
<a href="" class="button">Cancel</a>
```

I have tried doing this, which does submit the form, but it seems as though the `name="cancel"` is being lost, and the form simply submits without :

```
<a class="button" name="cancel" href="javascript:" onclick="$('#frmCompose').submit();">Cancel</a>
```

Because we are under a deadline, there is no time for rewriting the backend functionality for this.

How can I replace these old `<input type="image" />` with `<a>` tags and still pass along a `name` attribute? I would like to avoid having to create new CSS styles for `<button>` or `<input type="submit" />` if at all possible.

Comment: `<a href="?name=cancel" class="button">Cancel</a>`

Comment: @eicto: I assume he wants to submit the rest of the form too.

Comment: I think you'd need to use JS to, for example, put a value into a hidden field for the submit, and submit.

Comment: @Rocket Correct, there is also a `to`, `subject`, and `body` that gets submitted.

Comment: The proposed alternative is worse than the original. The original works without JS, whereas the second breaks easily...

Comment: also, what is reason to use <a> ? buttons/image input can be styled with css to look the same

Comment: The only real reason for using <a> is styling <input> or <button> can be much more difficult and inconsistent across browsers. I may have to resort to that...

Comment: check this: http://jsfiddle.net/ByLZH/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If adding name="cancel" to your  doesn't work, it sounds like you might have to get a little fancy with your javascript.  Something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="placeholder" value="true" />
<a class="button" name="cancel" href="javascript:" onclick="$(this).prev().attr('name', 'cancel'); $('#frmCompose').submit();">Cancel</a>
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `prev` in this case, that's brittle.

Comment: This was the closest answer to my eventual solution:
`<input type="hidden" class="form_action" name="" value="true" />`
`<a class="square small faded left" href="" onclick="$('.form_action').attr('name', 'cancel');$('#frmCompose').submit();return false;">Cancel</a>`

I was having added difficulty because the controller was checking for:
    `if ($_POST['cancel_x'])`
instead if
    `if ($_POST['cancel'])`
because the inputs were `type="image"`

Comment: @DaveNewton, I agree prev() is brittle, just using to illustrate functionality.  Looks like velocityhead used a class selector instead, which definitely feels cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Uglyish, but use a hidden form field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="clickedname" name="" value="" />
```

and

```
<a class="button" name="cancel" href="javascript:" onclick="$('#clickedname').value = this.name; $('#frmCompose').submit();">Cancel</a>
                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Adjust the name/value assignments to suit - I can't remember offhand exactly how image inputs submit themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use JS to, for example, put a value into a hidden field for the submit, and submit.

I'd recommend writing a tiny utility function that replaces your `onclick` attribute value. Better yet, attach the functionality after DOM ready and keep things unobtrusive and localized.

```html
<a class="button" href="#" onclick="submit('cancel')">Cancel</a>
```

And `submit` does what you'd expect, fills the hidden field, and submits the form. If you really can't change the back end at *all* then you can change the name of the hidden field as well, but ugh; seems like changing the back end to check for an "action" field or something is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Only form elements (`<input>`, `<button>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`, etc.) submit values to a form.  For an `<a>` tag to do so, you'd have to use JavaScript to add the value to a form.

One way is to add a hidden form element, and set its name/value.

```
<a class="button" name="cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
<input type="hidden" id="buttonClicked" />
```

Then using JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$(function(){
    $('a.button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#buttonClicked').prop({
            name: $(this).prop('name'),
            value: $(this).prop('name')
        });
        $('#frmCompose').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: @eicto: Yes, yes it is.  In the question, he was using `$('#frmCompose').submit();`, so I assumed he was using jQuery.

Comment: This is the nicest solution (so far); I missed it was jQuery originally since it wasn't tagged as such and I can't read.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a single hidden field to the form

```
<input type="hidden" id="action" value=""/>
```

Then set the value of action in the onclick

```
$("#action").attr("name","---ActionHere---");
```

So cancel becomes:

```
<a class="button" href="javascript:" onclick='$("#action").attr("name","cancel");$("#frmCompose").submit();'>Cancel</a>
```

And send becomes:

```
<a class="button" href="javascript:" onclick='$("#action").attr("name","send");$("#frmCompose").submit();'>Send</a>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is just to create an `<input type="hidden" />` with the name you want, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cancel" />
<a class="button" href="javascript:" onclick="$('#frmCompose').submit();">Cancel</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you not need to use `<a>` ?

html:

```
<button class="alike">Test</button>
<a href="#">Test</a>​
```

css:

```
button.alike,a {
 border: 0px;   
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #00E;
 width: auto;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: inherit;
 font-family: 'Times New Roman';
 font-size: 16px;
}​
```